# Facing cypress error as"cy.click() failed because it requires a DOM element. The subject received was: > undefined" after .click( ) on button

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

Facing cypress error as `cy.click() failed because it requires a DOM element.  The subject received was: > undefined" after .click( )` on button

```
it('with select tag test',function(){
    cy.visit('https://www.htse.net/')
    //pop up message window disappear 
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.get('.splashPopUp.show > .modal-dialog > .modal-content > .close > span',{timeout: 30000})
    //cy.get(" div[class='splashPopUp modal fade show'] span[aria-hidden='true']")
    //cy.get("div[class='splashPopUp modal fade show'] button[aria-label='Close']")
    
    cy.wait(2000)
   .click()
    //.should('be.visible')
  // cy.click({ force: true })
   /*cy.on('window:alert',(str)=>{
       expect(strt).to,equal('Aloha!')
   })*/
    cy.contains('ALOHA e Komo Mai')
    cy.click({ force: true })
})
```

Comment: Your `.click()` is chained to the `cy.wait()` which does not yield a jQuery element. You can read about this in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

`.click()` is a child command , you need to click on something so it should be preceded by a command that returns an element, like `.get()`, `.find()`, etc.

Ref [click command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Usage)

> **Incorrect Usage**
>
> `cy.click('.btn')` // Errors, cannot be chained off 'cy'
> `cy.window().click()` // Errors, 'window' does not yield DOM element

Looks like you want to click the 'X' top-right of modal,

```js
cy.contains('div.modal-dialog', 'Where is all the inventory')
  .find('button.close')
  .click()               // don't use multiple!
```

You can even just click on the gray background

```js
cy.get('div.splashPopUp')
  .click()
```

Comment: Seems there are many modals on the page, and they all have the same id of "exampleModal" which is bad news for testers! You can get the correct one by checking some of the text inside. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for guiding me, I applied your suggestions, pop up window disappeared from the home page but facing below mentioned error. Kindly give me some time for its solution also

**CypressError**

Timed out retrying after 4100ms: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">...</button>
```

This element <button.close> is not visible because its parent <div#exampleModal.splashPopUp.modal.fade> has CSS property: display: none

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.Learn more

7 |   cy.get('div.modal-dialog')
8 |   .find('button.close')

> 9 |   .click({ multiple: true })
> |    ^